# How to use Server Side variables on Markup

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, .net, user-controls

I want to use Session variable's value on the markup. This is the code written on UserContorl.ascx, file on NavigateUrl I want to send the Username which is stored in the session variable. I don't want to set NavigateUrl value on PageLoad function for some reason.

> Note the code gives the error: The server tag is not well formed.

```
<asp:Panel ID="pnlMenuItems" runat="server" HorizontalAlign="Left">
        <asp:HyperLink ID="LinkLogout" runat="server" NavigateUrl="~/logout/"+
            <%= HttpContext.Current.Session["UserName"].ToString(); %>> CssClass="pnlMenuItems"
            ForeColor="#666666">Logout</asp:HyperLink>
</asp:Panel>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bind data within server tags. e.g.

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="LinkLogout" runat="server"
    NavigateUrl="<%# LogoutUrl %>"
    CssClass="pnlMenuItems"
    ForeColor="#666666">Logout</asp:HyperLink>
```

then in your code behind:

```
protected string LogoutUrl { 
    get { 
        return "~/logout/" + HttpContext.Current.Session["UserName"].ToString(); 
    }
}

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    if(!IsPostBack) { DataBind(); }
}
```

The NavigateUrl gets set during the call to `DataBind()` using this method. In my example, the value would get set during page load, but you wouldn't have to specifically do it. If you need it to happen at a different time during the page lifecycle, you can try calling `DataBind()` during a different event.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
<asp:Panel ID="pnlMenuItems" runat="server" HorizontalAlign="Left">
        <asp:HyperLink ID="LinkLogout" runat="server"
            NavigateUrl="<%# "~/logout/" + HttpContext.Current.Session["UserName"].ToString() %>"
            CssClass="pnlMenuItems"
            ForeColor="#666666">Logout</asp:HyperLink>
</asp:Panel>
```

Comment: Error: Server tags cannot contain <% ... %> constructs.
it dose not worked